# Ubuntu #cloud-config cloud.init: Can't run conda commands to install new packages

Tags: bash, cloud, ubuntu-16.04, root, su

On a Ubuntu Digital Ocean, I want a Cloud.Init script to set up new droplet according to my needs.
I can set up a new user with sudo,remove Rootlogin, set up Fail2ban and ufw, install Docker, Miniconda, remove Rootlogin.
But I can't have a runcmd: that runs conda commands like conda update and conda install.
Working:

```
#cloud-config
package_update: true
package_upgrade: true
groups:
  - docker
users:
  - name: babar
    ssh-authorized-keys:
      - ssh-rsa AAAA.......
    sudo: ['ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL']
    groups: [sudo,docker]
    shell: /bin/bash
packages:
  - fail2ban
  - mosh
  - apt-transport-https
  - ca-certificates
  - curl
  - software-properties-common
  - docker-ce
apt:
  sources:
    curtin-dev-ppa.list:
      source: "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $RELEASE stable"
      keyid: 0EBFCD88 # GPG key ID published on a key server     
runcmd:
  - sed -i -e '/^PermitRootLogin/s/^.*$/PermitRootLogin no/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
  - sed -i -e '$aAllowUsers babar' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
  - restart ssh
  - ufw allow OpenSSH
  - ufw allow 60000:61000/udp
  - ufw enable
  - service fail2ban start
  - wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O /home/babar/miniconda.sh
  - 'su -c "bash /home/babar/miniconda.sh -b -p /home/babar/miniconda3" babar'
  - echo 'export PATH="$HOME/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"' >> /home/babar/.bashrc
```

Can't make a conda install from here, logs show conda unknown command
tried various stuff:

```
  -  'su -c "bash source /home/babar/miniconda3/bin/activate" babar'
  -  'su -c "bash conda install -y jupyter" babar'


  - source /home/babar/miniconda3/bin/activate
  - conda install -y jupyter
```

Jupyter is never installed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just to confirm that I can do conda commands when I log in via SSH

Comment: Hi! Did you find any solution yet?